# How to programmatically get underlying OS details of Azure VM

Tags: java, azure

Using Service Management REST APIs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx) we can get list of VM under our subscription.

Now i want to get the details of the underlying OS as well.. like which version of windows is installed, RAM, Processor, free HDD space etc.

Is there any API provided by Microsoft for this ? I am looking for a solution compatible with Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using service management API you can get the size of the role instance (Small, Medium etc). Each size has predefined number of cores, RAM, Hard Disk size etc. so you can find this information that way. Service management API won't give you this information directly.

Comment: Good idea. But still details like Free disk space, MAC address etc cannot be obtained. I was hoping against hope that Microsoft would have provided these.
Need to think of some indirect way .

Also for the role instance (Small, Medium etc) .. if there API to get predefined cores, RAM etc or have to manually check from UI.

Thanks again for your quick reply

Comment: For free disk space, since the VHD containing the OS is a page blob, you can get occupied page ranges to get an approximate idea about used space. Subtract that from total blob size to get free space. Not sure about the Mac address. AFAIK, there's no API to get details about RAM etc from VM size. HTH.

Comment: -- MAC address etc cannot be obtained

Comment: -- MAC address etc cannot be obtained

You shouldn't even dream about getting MAC address since that will change whenever Microsoft performs a server healing operation and moved your VM from one physical server to another. It will also change if you rehydrate a VM following a shutdown/deallocate operation.

Comment: Makes sense. Will try page blob thing.

Comment: I'm not sure how much sense it makes for information like OS version to be exposed via an API. VM's aren't exclusively Windows, after all.